# Hide Checkbox on a particular page

Tags: asp.net

I am working on ASP.NET application where I am reusing a user control. The user control contains a checkbox and bunch of other controls. I want to display all the controls inside the user control on all the pages but on one single page I want to hide the checkbox.

I was thinking that I can use the databind methods and see if I am on the "pagex" then hide the checkbox. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the code for the control you should be add a new property to the control for hiding/showing the checkbox and then just pass in the property depending upon what page you are on.  You'd have to pass in the show/hide property on the load event of the page.

Do you have access to the code??

Answer (score 0):

I would specify a parameter in the code behind for your ascx file.  Example:

```
public bool HideCB = false;
```

THen when you put your User Control on your aspx page do this:

```
<uc:TestControl id="TestControl" runat="Server" HideCB="true" />
```

This way you can do a check on `if(HideCB)` to determine if you want to make it visible or not.